# Getting Actionmailer to send list of overdue tasks in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to send my users an email via cron, each with a list of their due tasks. I can send an email to each user with overdue tasks. In my email template, I can display ALL overdue tasks. What I can't do is list only a specific user's tasks.

First of all, I have created a scope which finds all the users with due tasks:

Users.rb

```
scope :tasksdue, lambda {
       joins("join tasks on tasks.user_id = users.id").
       where("tasks.dueddate >= ? AND tasks.status = ?", Date.today, false).
       group("users.id")
     }
```

Also in my users model, I find and send these users an email:

```
def self.send_reminders
         User.tasksdue.find_each do |user|
         UserMailer.deliver_task_due user 
       end
end
```

And, in my view, I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello! <%= @user.name %></h1>

    <% User.listtasks.find_each do |task| %>
  <li> <%= task.tasks.title %> </li>
<% end %>

  </body>
```

The problem is the tasks due part. I'm calling a scope from my users model:

```
 scope :listtasks, lambda {
   joins("join tasks on tasks.user_id = users.id").
   where("tasks.dueddate >= ? AND tasks.user_id = ? AND tasks.status = ?", Date.today, :id, false)       
}
```

Using this, I get an error:

> undefined method `title' for #

I've also tried calling from Tasks.rb

```
 scope :tasksdue, lambda { 
     where("dueddate >= ? AND user_id = ? AND status = ?", Date.today, Task.user_id, false)
  }
```

Which complains about user_id.

I can get it to list all global overdue tasks, but not per user.

What do I need to do so it only lists the tasks per user??

-- EDIT ---

As per advice from @ream88 below, I created two independent scopes and in my Tasks controller for open and overdue:

```
scope :overdue, lambda { where('dueddate >= ?', Date.today) }
scope :open, where(:status => false)
```

Now I don't know how to iterate through these. I have tried this in my actionmailer template but the email is the same for each user...

```
<% Task.open.overdue.find_each do |task| %>
<%= task.title %>
<% end %>
```

How can I specify user in this request??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a lot of built-in functionally on your own, why? My opinion:

Create a `has_many` association in your `User` model and the corresponding `belongs_to` association in your `Task` model (if not already done):

```
# user.rb
has_many :tasks

# task.rb
belongs_to :user
```

And add following scopes to `Task`:

```
scope :overdue, lambda { where('dueddate >= ?', Date.today) }
scope :open, where(:status => false)
```

And now you're able to access overdue tasks for a specific user via: `user.tasks.open.overdue`. (You can probably create only one scope in your `Task` model including both search criteria, but my opinion is to split my code into the smallest pieces possible.)

---

```
# mailer.rb
def task_due(user)
  @user, @tasks = user, user.tasks.open.overdue
  mail(:to => user.mail, :subject => 'Do your work! Dammit!') do |as|
    as.html { render('your/email/partial') }
    as.text { render('your/email/partial') }
  end
end

# your/email/partial.html.erb
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li><%= task %></li>
<% end %>

# your/email/partial.text.erb
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  * <%= task %>
<% end %>

# models/user.rb
def self.send_mails_to_lazy_users
  # Remind lazy user about their tasks!
  # This function should be called in a controller, after a specific button was pressed or in a background task, like delayed_job
  includes(:tasks).where(:tasks => ['duedate >= ? AND status = ?', Date.today, false]).each do |lazy_user|
    Mailer.task_due(lazy_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Should this part go in my view? How does it iterate through the tasks?

Comment: hello again @ream88. Thanks for the answer, could you let me know where I'm support to put the user.tasks.open.overdue ?? I put it in my actionmailer email view but get no output :( Jx

Comment: Cool, let me check through and see if I can figure it out. Jx

Comment: Am going to have to think this through properly. The code above gives me an error: "Don't know how to build task 'cron:send_reminders'" No idea why this is causing me so many problems... Jx

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, I couldn't quite get your code to work but it certainly helped me understand what I was actually doing... Thanks!! Jx

Comment: Cool. Was looking through the first tutorial I used to leave AM. Can see why I got in a state. The Interweb's too full of junk! Thanks again jx